# Sticky Element not Working on Iphone CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I just want my IMG sticky whenever I scroll. 
This code is working on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.
But not using safari. This may be a simple situation for some professionals but for me, I'm having a bad situation whenever I get stacked on a single error.

Here's my css code

```
.stickyTop{
 position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

and here's my HTML code

```
<img class="stickyTop" style="width: 100%; height:auto;" src="img/CH_Beginner.jpg">
```

Maybe there's other appropriate code that will fit in safari?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
-webkit-position: sticky;
```

Comment: This is not the correct way of writing it. It should be: position:-webkit-sticky;